# Select primary phone number (if exist) else select the latest phone number one using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the scenario,

**Table1:**

| Phone Number id | Person_id |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 001 |
| 12346 | 001 |
| 12347 | 001 |
| 12348 | 002 |
| 12349 | 002 |
| 12350 | 003 |

**Table2:**

| Person_id | primary phone id |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 12346 |
| 002 |  |
| 003 | 12350 |

There are two tables, table1 and table2
I want to fetch phone number based on person_id and condition is that,

if the phone number id is primary (which is present in table2 is primary ), select the primary number else select the phone number that is less

for e.g.
here is what i want, i have used sub queries but its making query slow for 200 000 person id

output:

| Person_id | Phone Number id |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 12346 |
| 002 | 12348 |
| 003 | 12350 |

Comment: What does this mean?  "select the phone number that is less". Less than what?

Comment: smaller i mean. for e.g. for id 002 the phone number id should be 12348 not 12349

Comment: Hi @VishalYadav which mysql version do you use? All column data type is string or int?

Comment: Oracle db. No need to worry about datatypes.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are completely different products. Since you said it's Oracle, I changed your tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the smallest number from the first table when there is none in the second, then one method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.personid, 
       coalesce(t2.primary_phone_number,
                (select min(t1.phone_number)
                 from table1 t1
                 where t1.personid = t2.personid
                )
               ) as imputed_primary_phone_number
from table2 t2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using subqueries in big tables is not good performance wise. I recommend to left join tables and take min or max value from the second table.

```
       SELECT NVL (t1.phone_number, t1.phone_number) phone_number
  FROM table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN (phone_number) AS phone_number, person_id
                    FROM table2
                  GROUP BY person_id) t2
           ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN if atleast one phone number exists of each person_id in table2. subquery block returns person wise minimum phone number. Then it joins with table1 for getting expected result.

```
-- MySQL (v5.6)
SELECT t.person_id
     , COALESCE(t.primary_phone_id, p.phone_number_id) phone_number_id
FROM table2 t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT person_id
                , MIN(phone_number_id) phone_number_id
           FROM table1
           GROUP BY person_id) p
       ON t.person_id = p.person_id;
```

Please check the url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20512e/3

Comment: Hi @VishalYadav please check the query and let me know if any query. I've written this one think about optimization or large data set.